# Сокращенная запись

Tags: php, javascript

Вот писал код, и мне стало интересно.

Допустим, у меня есть нечто такое:

```js
if( a == 'Значение 1' || a == 'Значение 2' || a == 'Значение 3'){
 //[некоторый код 1]
}else if( a == 'Значение 4' || a == 'Значение 5' ){
  //[некоторый код 2]
}
```

(Значение 1 ... 5 - это какие-то произвольные значения, строки или числа - не важно)

Возможно ли как-то записать подобное выражение более кратко, чтобы не писать по многу раз "a=="? (допустим, "a" - еще короткое название переменной, но, в случае с длинным, все это вообще вытягивается, порой, безобразно)

Сейчас интересует, в первую очередь Java Script, но, если кто на php или на java знает - тоже буду рад услышать :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
switch (a) {
   case 'Значение 1':
   case 'Значение 2':
   case 'Значение 3':
       // код 1
       break;
   case 'Значение 4':
   case 'Значение 5':
       // код 2
       break;
}
```

Comment: Хм) Не додумался до такого решения) Благодарю!

Answer (score 6):

Можно написать следующим образом

```
if ( ['Значение 1', 'Значение 2', 'Значение 3'].indexOf( a ) != -1 ){
 //[некоторый код 1]
}else if( ['Значение 4', 'Значение 5'].indexOf( a ) != -1 ){
  //[некоторый код 2]
}
```

Comment: Да, интересный способ, благодарю!

Answer (score 6):

В php это функция `in_array()`:

```
if(in_array($a,[1,2,3])){
    // код1
}elseif(in_array($a,[4,5])){
    // код2
}
```

Comment: благодарю, буду знать!

Answer (score 0):

это не совсем прямое решение (и стоит дважды проверить, что там со строгостью типов), но лучше вы не найдете

```
if (a in [1, 2, 3]) {

} else if (a in [4, 5]) {

}
```

Comment: Хм, выглядит красиво, но не сработает: in ищит по ключу

Comment: Для in должно быть как-то так, чтобы сработало: (a in {'Значение 1' : true, 'Значение 2': true, 'Значение 3' : true})

Comment: @GrinyaLesnoy мой факап